# Ordinal notations and the Church-Kleene Ordinal

Tags: computability, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

According to Kleene, an $r$-system is a pair $(S, |\cdot|)$ where $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and $|\cdot|$ maps $S$ to countable ordinals, such that

1. There is a partial recursive $K(x)$, such that $K(x) = 0$ iff $|x| = 0$, $K(x) = 1$ iff $|x|$ is a successor ordinal and $K(x) = 2$ iff $|x|$ is a limit ordinal.
2. There is a partial recursive $P(x)$, such that for all $x\in S$ with $K(x) = 1$ we have $P(x)\in S$ with $|P(x)| + 1 = |x|$.
3. There is a partial recursive $Q(x, t)$, such that for all $x\in S$ with $K(x) = 2$ we have $Q(x, t)\in S$ for all $t$ and $|Q(x, t)|$ is strictly increasing in $t$ with limit $|x|$.

Now the well-known Church-Kleene ordinal is (by definition) the supremum of all ordinals that have a name in some $r$-system.

Say we restrict to those $r$-systems where we additionally require that the set $S$ should be recursive. Then what is the limit of all ordinals that have a name in such a restricted $r$-system?

Answer (score 2):

It's still $\omega_1^{CK}$. In fact, $\omega_1^{CK}$ is extremely robust; it is for example the supremum of the ordertypes of the polynomial-time-computable well-orderings of $\mathbb{N}$, as well as the supremum of the ordertypes of the $\Sigma^1_1$ well-orderings of $\mathbb{N}$. The former claim is pretty easy to show, and is a good exercise; the latter claim is a hard theorem (see [Sacks' book *Higher recursion theory*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/toc/pl/1235422631)).

(In fact, my impression is that most modern texts **do** define $\omega_1^{CK}$ as the supremum of the ordertypes of the computable well-orderings of computable subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the classical book on higher recursion theory by Sacks defines $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$ using Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$. But doesn't this statement make Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$ quite unattractive, given that there is a "better" notation in the sense that being a code is also decidable. Or am I missing the point here? Maybe there is no maximal such restricted system which can name *all* constructive ordinals?

Comment: @Achilles There's no way you can get the set of codes to be decidable: if $\mathcal{C}$ is a decidable set of codes, consider $\sum_{n\in\mathcal{C}}[n]$ where $[n]$ is the interpretation of the code $n$. In fact, you can't even get a $\Sigma^1_1$ set of codes (look up "$\Sigma^1_1$ bounding"). Separately, even if a bit technical the definition via $\mathcal{O}$ has a number of useful properties (which Sacks' book goes into).

Comment: @Achilles For each $\alpha<\omega_1^{CK}$, there is a recursive coding system that codes all the ordinals $\leq\alpha$. But no single recursive coding system works for all the ordinals$<\omega_1^{CK}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It may be useful for other readers (if not for the OP) to extend your remark about "extremely robust" in the other direction, up to hyperarithmetical.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Done!